# Convert tree to list of full paths in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, tree

I am trying to convert a tree structure into a list of paths.

The tree looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Default Category',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Carpet',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Colour',
            'children' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'White',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Grey',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              2 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Black',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              3 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Light',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              4 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Medium',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              5 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Dark',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Style',
            'children' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Twist Pile Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Stainfree Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              2 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Saxony and Shagpile Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              3 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Soft Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              4 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Loop Pile & Berber Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              5 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Wool Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              6 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Striped & Patterned Carpet',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              7 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Natural Carpets',
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

And my end result would be an array that looks like this:

```
Default Category/
Default Category/Carpet
Default Category/Carpet/Colour
Default Category/Carpet/Colour/White
Default Category/Carpet/Colour/Grey
Default Category/Carpet/Colour/Black
...
Default Category/Carpet/Style/
Default Category/Carpet/Style/Twist Pile Carpets
Default Category/Carpet/Style/Stainfree Carpets
```

I am aware that I need to use recursion here and I can iterate the tree, but I am not sure how to build a list of paths as it traverses the tree.

I have tried searching, but I am not finding anything close to what I specifically need and I seem to have this impression that the tree I am working with is a multi-way tree and this is slightly different to tackle.

Some suggestions are to simplify the tree but I have already done this by removing other unnecessary keys and I have seen that suggestions to flatten the array to make the traversal process easier but it is not clear in my mind how that would work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 2**

This is what I have currently and it works for the first path, which is: Default Category/Carpet/Colour/White but the second path will not carry Default Category/Carpet/Colour/ over and this is ultimately what I am trying to figure out how to do.

```
function generateCategoryPaths($categoryTree, &$paths = null, &$path = null)
{
    if (! $paths) {
        $paths = [];
    }

    foreach ($categoryTree as $category) {
        $path .= $category['name'];
        if (isset($category['children']) && count($category['children']) > 0) {
            $path .= '/';
            generateCategoryPaths($category['children'], $paths, $path, $level);
            continue;
        }

        $paths[] = $path;
        $path = '';
    }

    return $paths;
}
```

And calling code:

```
$categoryPaths = generateCategoryPaths($categories);
```

This will return the following:

```
array (
  0 => 'Default Category/Carpet/Colour/White',
  1 => 'Grey',
  2 => 'Black',
  3 => 'Light',
  4 => 'Medium',
  5 => 'Dark',
  6 => 'Style/Twist Pile Carpets',
  7 => 'Stainfree Carpets',
  8 => 'Saxony and Shagpile Carpets',
  9 => 'Soft Carpets',
  10 => 'Loop Pile & Berber Carpets',
  11 => 'Wool Carpets',
  12 => 'Striped & Patterned Carpet',
  13 => 'Natural Carpets',
  14 => 'Brand',
  15 => 'Room/Bedroom Carpet',
  16 => 'Living Room Carpet',
  17 => 'Hall, Stairs & Landing Carpet',
  18 => 'Office Carpet',
  19 => 'Conservatory Carpet',
  20 => 'Dining Room Carpet',
  21 => 'Whole House',
  22 => 'Vinyl/Colour/White',
  23 => 'Grey',
  24 => 'Black',
  25 => 'Light',
  26 => 'Medium',
  27 => 'Dark',
  28 => 'Style/Wood Effect Luxury Vinyl Flooring',
  29 => 'Tile Effect Luxury Vinyl Flooring',
  30 => 'Parquet Luxury Vinyl Flooring',
  31 => 'Plain',
  32 => 'Brand/Naturelle',
  33 => 'TLC',
  34 => 'Karndean Flooring',
  35 => 'Polyflor Flooring',
  36 => 'Amtico',
  37 => 'Quickstep Livyn',
  38 => 'COREtec Flooring',
  39 => 'Installation/Click Vinyl Flooring',
  40 => 'Stick Down Vinyl Flooring',
  41 => 'Laminate/Colour/White',
```

The first line is what I am trying to replicate it for each entry where it shows the path through the tree.

The second and subsequent lines will discard the current path and this is what I am trying to solve.

**Update 3**

JSON encoded version of the input tree:

```
[{"name":"Default Category","level":"1","children":[{"name":"Carpet","level":"2","children":[{"name":"Colour","level":"3","children":[{"name":"White","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Grey","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Black","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Light","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Medium","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Dark","level":"4","children":[]}]},{"name":"Style","level":"3","children":[{"name":"Twist Pile Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Stainfree Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Saxony and Shagpile Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Soft Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Loop Pile & Berber Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Wool Carpets","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Striped & Patterned Carpet","level":"4","children":[]},{"name":"Natural Carpets","level":"4","children":[]}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Comment: What have you tried before?

Comment: I have tried several things, but I am back at square one. I will try and work on returning to the version I had to provide some context.

Comment: Let us see your "best" failure.  And do us a favor -- post your input data as `var_export()` or json so that we can quickly get to work solving your issue.  Did you research any of the many recursive solutions on this site?

Comment: I have added my best failure, although previously I did not even get as close as having the first line show what I am trying to achieve. I also re-formatted the arrays - thanks for the tip! In terms of research, I have looked at a number of them but none seem to operate on the type of tree I have. I did try tampering with them to get the desired effect, but I feel I am lacking in the array handling department, which has never been my strong suit sadly and I think that is why I am having a hard time working this out.

Comment: json_encode the array, then we can play with the data ourselvezs

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have added a JSON encoded version of the tree.

Comment: Thanks! Check some old code I've wrote previously in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using recursion with a reference variable.  A reference variable, defined with this symbol "&", makes a php variable work asynchronously, meaning the definition is uniform regardless of where it is defined.

```
<?php
function listPaths(array $array=[], string $parent="", array &$names=[]):array
{

   foreach($array as $data){

     if(isset($data['name'])){
          $name = $parent."/".$data['name'];
          $names[] = $name;

        if(isset($data['children'])){
           listPaths($data['children'],$name,$names);
        }
     }
  }

    return $names;
}

$result = listPaths($array);
```

Comment: This works for listing the names of each category, but in my case, I need to generate the path to each category and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: That works perfectly. I have been trying to crack this for hours and when I look at your code, it seems so simple! I guess my problem was just not really knowing how to take advantage of recursion in the way you have. May make no difference to you, but I have credited you for the solution in the source code. This will certainly go towards helping me reach the next level in my programming career and I cannot thank you enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tree generator that created a `<ul>'s` with `<li>'s` that could contain other `<ul>'s` and `<li>'s`. You can read my blog post about it here https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/tree-generator-for-multi-dimensional-arrays/

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it shouldn't be too difficult to tweak this class to generate slashes instead of opening/closing tags! The recusrsion strategy is what matters! Good luck!

```
class Tree
{
    private $data;
    private $html;

    public function buildTree(array $data, $parent_id)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->html = '<ul>';
        $this->getChildren($parent_id);
        $this->html .= '</ul>';
        return $this->html;
    }

    private function getChildren($parentId)
    {
        $children = array();
        foreach ($this->data as $row) {
            if ($row['parentid'] == $parentId) {
                $children[] = $row;
            }
        }
        foreach($children as $child)
        { 
            $this->html .= '<li>'.$child['name'].'<ul>';
            $this->getChildren($child['id']); 
            $this->html .= '</ul></li>';
        } 

    }
}


$tree = new Tree();
$ul = $tree->buildTree($data, 0);
echo $ul;
```

Comment: I think this would be work for my use case if my tree had IDs for the parent and child, but perhaps, this is why I am finding it difficult in the first place. I feel recursion is a pretty simple concept, but I have not used it much in real world.